# Cassanda, the available RAM is used to a maximum

Tags: cassandra, heap-memory

I want to make a simple query over approximately 10 mio rows.
I have 32GB RAM (20GB is free). And Cassandra is using so much memory, that the available RAM is used to a maximum, and the process is killed.
How can I optimize Cassandra? I have read about "Tuning Java resources" and changing the Java heap sizing, but I still have no solution.

Comment: 10 mio rows in one partiton? Or different partitions?

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra will use up as much memory as is available to it on the system. It's a greedy process and will use any available memory for caching, similar to the way the kernel page cache works. Don't worry if Cassandra is using all your hosts memory, it will just be in cache and will be released to other processes if necessary.

If your query is suffering from timeouts this will probably be from reading too much data from a single partition so that the query doesn't return in under read_request_timeout_in_ms. If this is the case you should look at making your partition sizes smaller.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 
Yes, it is really greedy process.. it takes about 15 Minutes till my RAM is used to a maximum. And then I get a message "Process killed".
So there is no way how I can reduce this usage? Only to make my partition smaller?

Comment: Probably, there are lots of things that could affect memory usage though. Are you querying data when this occurs? Are you running other processes on the machine? The fact that you get Process killed implies it's the kernel killing the daemon - which doesn't necessarily mean it's using up too much memory but your system as a whole is (and Cassandra has the highest oom killer score).